# expresion regular que valide un dni y un cif en el mismo campo

Tags: javascript, angular

he desarrollado un formulario en angular y tengo un campo que es cif, en el que con una expresion regular lo valido. Mi duda surge cuando estoy intentando que en ese campo del formulario, se pueda introducir tanto un dni como un cif. El caso es que no doy con al combinación de la expresion regular para que me funcione. O me funciona una o la otra o ninguna, pero no consigo que me valide las dos combinaciones.

Expresión para el cif

```
('^([ABCDFGHJKLMNPQRSUVWabcdfghlmnpqrsuvw])([0-9]{7})([0-9A-Ja]$'), Validators.required, Validators.maxlength(9)]);
```

y para el dni se que es como se muestra a continuación, pero no se como imoplementarlo con el del cif para que me permita los dos, he intentado varias combinaciones pero no doy con ello.Mil gracias

```
('^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$'), Validators.required, Validators.maxlength(9)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que estas usando las clases [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) de **Angular** necesitas usar el operador **or** `|` en tu **Regex** para poder *validar* una u otra expresión, de esta manera:

**Ejemplo de esto:**

```js
([(/^[A-Va-w][0-9]{8}[A-Z]$|^[0-9]{7}[0-9A-Ja]$/), Validators.required, Validators.maxlength(9)])
```

---

No estoy seguro que método exacto estas usando, pero lo que te interesa de allí es la **regex** y el operador `|` **or**

Te dejo un ejemplo de el **método** [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) de **Javascript**

```js
let valido = /^[A-Va-w][0-9]{8}[A-Z]$|^[0-9]{7}[0-9A-Ja]$/.test('V1234567a')

console.log(valido)
```

Puedes ejecutarlo y veras que su salida sera igual a `true`.

##### Nota:

Puedes usar el **modificador** que mejor te convenga te dejo un poco más de información de eso [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Un saludo :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el operador OR lo había usado pero debe ser que no, de forma correcta.

Comment: Perfecto @JavierFalcon, recuerda marcar como **check** la respuesta que te sea útil y solucione tu problema, para que la pregunta quede como *solucionada*

Comment: he puesto lo que me has sugerido pero no me funciona ni dni ni cif, nose si estoy ciego o bloqueado ya jajaja esto es lo que he puesto en su totalidad. `this.oportunityForm.controls['cif'].setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$ | [A-Va-w][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Ja]$/g'), Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(9)]);`

Comment: Es que como te dije no estoy seguro que método usabas para hacer la validación. Pero ya me queda claro, ya edito la respuesta amigo @JavierFalcon

Comment: @JavierFalcon **Corrección:** creo que debería funcionar, solo que entre el **operador** `|` no van espacios y tampoco lo pases como **string** pasalo sin las *comillas* `Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$|[A-Va-w][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Ja]$/)` como **regex**. Y olvida el modificador `g`

Comment: Prueba así y me comentas ;)

Comment: No me funciona tampoco. Es que es un formulario reactivo de angular, lo que hago es ejercer un control en el formulario con campos obligatorios a rellenar. En el caso del CIF que lleva letra  primera y luego 8 digitos, quiero que tambien se pueda poner DNI, lo que pasa es que en el form.control cif esta  como string, entonces el regex tambien debería asi es como lo tenia antes. Porque si lo pongo sin las comillas no me funciona y si lo pongo con comillas tampogo. Basicamente no me da valido ni el formato CIF ni el DNI.

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta @JavierFalcon prueba con eso, sino te funciona entonces significa que estoy mal entendiendo algo acerca de **Angular**. Por cierto no te preocupes en que le pases una **regex** y no un **string** allí no debería haber problemas

Answer (score 1):

Viendo las dos expresiones regulares entiendo que los cif son del estilo:
A3456789F, G12345678,
Mientras los DNI
23456178N
Es decir que la cadena debe cumplir con el primer modelo **O** con el segundo. La clave está en el O, por eso si unes ambas expresiones con un O (la barra vertical) te debe funcionar

```
/(^[ABCDFGHJKLMNPQRSUVWabcdfghlmnpqrsuvw]([0-9]{7})([0-9A-Ja]$))|(^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$)/
```

Aunque, supongo que te has dado cuenta de que solo acepta letras minúsculas al final para el DNI.
**EDITO**
Algunas muestras que no pasan por que no concuerdan con el patrón:

```js
patron= /(^[ABCDFGHJKLMNPQRSUVWabcdfghlmnpqrsuvw]([0-9]{7})([0-9A-Ja]$))|(^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$)/;
console.log("23456789: "+ patron.test("23456789"));
console.log("23456789ABC "+ patron.test("23456789ABC"));
console.log("A2345678 "+ patron.test("A1234567"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda,  voy a probar esto y os comento. porque entre tanto corchetye y parentesis igual no los ponía como debería. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona, lo que pasa es que es muy permisivo. Por ejemplo cuando le puse lo del cif si no cumplia la letra primero y los 8 numeros avisaba de campo erroneo. Pero ahora me permite  poner solo numeros y podria seguir avanzando, o  un dni con 3 letras tampoco se queja.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás validando? No admite ni solo números ni tres letras en el dni. Al go se me debe escapar. Edito la respuesta para poner ejemplos.